# Video signal through headphone jack (2 stripes) (component video)

Tags: video, input, headphone-jack

I have a few questions regarding the possibility to transfer video signals through specific cables.

I have a cable that has a yellow and a white component plug on one side, and a headphone jack on the other. I've been searching a bit and I found that it would be possible to send video signals through a headphone out, as long as the plug has 3 stripes instead of 2.

In this case I would want to plug my Nintendo 64 on the component end and my Victory portable DVD player on the headphone side. It has an input for a headphone jack for audio and one for video too. (both inputs)

I wonder if it's possible to use the cable I described for that purpose, and if there would be a chance I could damage either of the devices.

Thanks in advance
Greetings Mathias

Comment: Would help if you posted where you read this was possible.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/21506/3-5mm-headphone-jack-component-video?rq=1

Comment: The accepted answer is pretty clear with regards to the standard headphone jacks and the required stripping on the 3.5mm plug in order to do this. Intergrate your research into your post.  Your plug only has 2 stripes which means it can only support audio.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong in the assumption (from reading your description): Your nintendo 64 has 3 RCA OUT for Video, and Stereo Audio (Usually yellow, white, and red RCA plugs) and Your Victory Portable DVD player has 2 x 3.5mm Jack, one for Headphone, and one for Video?

Comment: yes, it also has one for spdif and audio out, all with 3,5 mm's.

Answer (score 1):

Since your portable DVD players has two *separate* inputs for audio and video, your best, and safest, bet would be to use two RCA to 1/8 inch jack [cables](http://www.ecogneato.com/images/support/stge/pabv/2/i1.jpg).  Hook one up to video and one for audio.  The cables are cheap and can be bought from any electronics store.  Since the jacks are labeled separately, odds are there is no support for an integrated AV source.